# AJAX and XmlHttpRequest check

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a page that send data with POST method to a PHP file using Ajax.

My issue is that the loading icon ( Spinner) disappear before the content is loaded in the page.

---

```
$(function () {

    jQuery.ajaxSetup ({

      beforeSend: function()  {
         $('#spinner').show();
    },

      complete: function() {
          $('#spinner').hide() },


      successy: function() {
          $('#spinner').hide() }
    });
```

---

I am using Firebug plug in in FireFox browser. When I check the XHR is still running but the loading icon stops as soon I click on the button.

How can the spinner keep going till the XHR is complete With the use of AJAX

Or any other alternative that you think will help me with this issue.

Comment: "successY" ? You're sure about the 'y' here ?

Comment: I mistyped it here, it is only success.

Comment: What button? Where's the code that generates request?